# Rails built child but parent id nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Build 2 different children just before parent is saved. I understand that when I write `parent.child.build` the parent's id is automatically given to the child.

Here, the first child is ok but the second one have a folder_id nil (It is a has_many relationship)

```
def create
    @folder = Folder.new(folder_params)

    @folder.events.build(scheduler_resource_id: SchedulerResource.where(user: @folder.maker).last.id,
                           start: @folder.production_date.beginning_of_month, end: @folder.production_date.end_of_month)

    @folder.events.build(scheduler_resource_id: SchedulerResource.where(user: @folder.analyst).last.id,
                           start: @folder.production_date.beginning_of_month, end: @folder.production_date.end_of_month)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @folder.save
        format.html { redirect_to @folder, notice: 'Folder was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @folder }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @folder.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I don't understand why the parent's id is not given to the second child.

**EDIT**

As asked, here is my Event model

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :date_range
  belongs_to :scheduler_resource
  belongs_to :folder

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :folder

  def self.select_folder
    Folder.all.map { |p| ["#{p.client.corporate_name} - #{p.concatenate_mandates} (#{p.status})", p.id] }
  end

  def all_day_event?
    start == start.midnight && self.end == self.end.midnight ? true : false
  end

end
```

Comment: I have tried an example similar to what you have shared and it worked fine. From my view problem lies some where building `events`. Can you please share your event model?

Comment: `build` can build array of objects so, you can build those 2 objects in a single build method by using array. Like `@books = @author.books.build([
  { published_at: Time.now, book_number: "A12346" },
  { published_at: Time.now, book_number: "A12347" }
])` . Though I am not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I added my model. The only thing different from any other models is that I have an accepts_nested_attributes for updating the parent in the child's form. Not sure if that can be an issue here.e

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I thought about that and tried. Did not work. I also thought it was overwritten because I made it a has_one instead of a has_many but no.

Comment: Can you try after removing `accepts_nested_attributes`? Sounds silly. But want to check

Comment: @PardeepDhingra I accepted Puhlze's answer as the correct one. The accepts_nested_attributes was not related here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code sample provided `@folder` is created with the `#new` method, which doesn't save the record. Unsaved records have no id, so there is no id to assign to child records instantiated with the `#build` method.

If @folder is a saved record when you call `events.build` the returned event model will have the saved parent id from `@folder` assigned to it as `folder_id`.

Comment: You're right, I built and saved the children afterward and it worked.Thanks a lot